# Using the ASP.NET MVC dynamic model/viewbag only a bad idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As the **sole** developer of an app, would using a dynamic model, or the new ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 3, exclusively be a bad idea (i.e., not building strongly typed classes)?

Currently, I have a strongly typed viewdata strategy that breaks the built-in html form helpers (like Html.TextBoxFor). My viewdata looks like this:

```
public class BaselineViewData {
  ...properties all views will need...
  public Area1ViewData Area1ViewData {get;set;}
  public Area2ViewData Area2ViewData {get;set;}
}
```

Some properties of the BaselineViewData are viewdata classes themselves. So far it's been great, but the form helpers don't work well. They output something like this:

@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Username) outputs

`<input id="BaselineViewData.Area1ViewData.Username" ... />`

With that naming, the built-in unobtrusive validation doesn't work.

I started this app with MVC 1, it's ported to MVC 3... but not taking advantage of all the benefits of MVC 3. So I decided I'm going to totally rewrite the app now, which will be much easier than it was then... now that there's so much handled for you. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be going with a hybrid strongly typed/viewbag viewdata strategy. I'll follow the example give in the accountmodels file in a default asp.net mvc 3 app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Weakly typed **anything** is more prone to errors than statically typed code.

You're throwing away one of C#'s greatest strengths by not using strongly typed views.

Comment: Yes, but being the only developer of the app... I'm not foreseeing so many errors to offset the ease/speed of development.

Comment: @Chad - You don't make typos?

Comment: Not that I wouldn't find through testing. I pretty much code/test in real-time. Make change, hit refresh... if it were a typo on the model, it would error out immediately.

Comment: @Chad, weakly typed views are a bad idea even if there's a 1/2 developer working on the project.

Comment: @Darin, thanks for joining in. What are the major trade-offs? From what I can see: speed of development vs less error prone. But if I'm careful, there shouldn't be any "sneaky" bugs that crop up from mistyped viewdata, correct? Are there features of ASP.NET MVC 3 that I simply would not be able to take advantage of if I solely used a dynamic model?

Comment: @Chad: Extension methods are one thing that comes to mind: you'd have to invoke them explicitly. Intellisense is also pretty nice. I think the hybrid strategy is good. Use a strongly-typed model as your main view model, but use ViewBag for things like Dropdown collections or DOM IDs that you're tracking on the side.